# Logtash | Multiple Pipelines

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to configure multiple pipelines for which I carried out the changes in pipelines.yml with simple test configuration, after removing all the code to debug to make it work. Below is the sample configuration now, initially, I specified two pipelines when it did not work, I reduced it to one. However, I am facing the below error every time. Any inputs will be very helpful. Thanks

**pipelines.yml**
[image]

**test.conf**

[image]

**Errors**

> [ERROR][logstash.config.sourceloader] Could not fetch all the sources
> {:exception=>NoMethodError, :message=>"undefined method each' for
> #String:0x20ddda4a

```
C:\tools\logstash-7.12.1\bin>logstash
Using JAVA_HOME defined java: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11
WARNING, using JAVA_HOME while Logstash distribution comes with a bundled JDK
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Sending Logstash logs to C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2021-05-21T03:52:18,708][INFO ][logstash.runner ] Log4j configuration path used is: C:\tools\logstash-7.12.1\config\log4j2.properties
[2021-05-21T03:52:18,735][INFO ][logstash.runner ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.12.1", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.13.0 (2.5.7) 2020-08-03 9a89c94bcc Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.11+9-LTS-194 on 11.0.11+9-LTS-194 +indy +jit [mswin32-x86_64]"}
[2021-05-21T03:52:21,190][ERROR][logstash.config.sourceloader] Could not fetch all the sources {:exception=>NoMethodError, :message=>"undefined method each' for #<String:0x20ddda4a>", :backtrace=>["C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:145:in merge_pipeline_settings'", "C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/config/source/multi_local.rb:36:in block in pipeline_configs'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2577:in map'", "C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/config/source/multi_local.rb:34:in pipeline_configs'", "C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/config/source_loader.rb:76:in block in fetch'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2572:in collect'", "C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/config/source_loader.rb:75:in fetch'", "C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:188:in converge_state_and_update'", "C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:126:in execute'", "C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:409:in block in execute'", "C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/task.rb:24:in block in initialize'"]}
[2021-05-21T03:52:21,283][INFO ][logstash.agent ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2021-05-21T03:52:21,454][ERROR][logstash.agent ] An exception happened when converging configuration {:exception=>RuntimeError, :message=>"Could not fetch the configuration, message: undefined method `each' for #String:0x20ddda4a"}
[2021-05-21T03:52:21,917][INFO ][logstash.runner ] Logstash shut down.
[2021-05-21T03:52:21,949][FATAL][org.logstash.Logstash ] Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
org.jruby.exceptions.SystemExit: (SystemExit) exit
at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:747) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:710) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
at C_3a_.tools.logstash_minus_7_dot_12_dot_1.lib.bootstrap.environment.(C:\tools\logstash-7.12.1\lib\bootstrap\environment.rb:89) ~[?:?]
```

**Error with Debug mode enabled**

```
C:\tools\logstash-7.12.1\bin>logstash --log.level debug
Using JAVA_HOME defined java: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11
WARNING, using JAVA_HOME while Logstash distribution comes with a bundled JDK
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Sending Logstash logs to C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2021-05-21T06:05:35,944][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Log4j configuration path used is: C:\tools\logstash-7.12.1\config\log4j2.properties
[2021-05-21T06:05:35,968][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.12.1", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.13.0 (2.5.7) 2020-08-03 9a89c94bcc Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.11+9-LTS-194 on 11.0.11+9-LTS-194 +indy +jit [mswin32-x86_64]"}
[2021-05-21T06:05:35,992][DEBUG][logstash.modules.scaffold] Found module {:module_name=>"fb_apache", :directory=>"C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/modules/fb_apache/configuration"}
[2021-05-21T06:05:35,995][DEBUG][logstash.plugins.registry] Adding plugin to the registry {:name=>"fb_apache", :type=>:modules, :class=>#<LogStash::Modules::Scaffold:0x65dcf80f @directory="C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/modules/fb_apache/configuration", @module_name="fb_apache", @kibana_version_parts=["6", "0", "0"]>}
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,027][DEBUG][logstash.modules.scaffold] Found module {:module_name=>"netflow", :directory=>"C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/modules/netflow/configuration"}
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,035][DEBUG][logstash.plugins.registry] Adding plugin to the registry {:name=>"netflow", :type=>:modules, :class=>#<LogStash::Modules::Scaffold:0x1b601570 @directory="C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/modules/netflow/configuration", @module_name="netflow", @kibana_version_parts=["6", "0", "0"]>}
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,185][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] -------- Logstash Settings (* means modified) ---------
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,195][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] *node.name: "logtash-node-zteucompass2" (default: "zteucompass2")
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,197][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] path.data: "C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/data"
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,199][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] modules.cli: <Java::OrgLogstashUtil::ModulesSettingArray:1 []>
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,207][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] modules: []
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,209][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] modules_list: []
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,211][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] modules_variable_list: []
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,212][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] modules_setup: false
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,213][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] config.test_and_exit: false
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,267][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] config.reload.automatic: false
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,273][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] config.reload.interval: #<Java::OrgLogstashUtil::TimeValue:0x48a8a298>
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,275][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] config.support_escapes: false
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,278][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] config.field_reference.parser: "STRICT"
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,299][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] metric.collect: true
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,307][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.id: "main"
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,335][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.system: false
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,360][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.workers: 2
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,367][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.batch.size: 125
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,369][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.batch.delay: 50
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,431][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.unsafe_shutdown: false
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,438][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.java_execution: true
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,439][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.reloadable: true
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,441][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.plugin_classloaders: false
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,442][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.separate_logs: false
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,443][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.ordered: "auto"
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,444][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] pipeline.ecs_compatibility: "disabled"
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,455][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] path.plugins: []
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,457][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] config.debug: false
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,459][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] *log.level: "debug" (default: "info")
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,460][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] version: false
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,463][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] help: false
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,469][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] log.format: "plain"
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,471][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] http.enabled: true
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,474][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] http.host: "127.0.0.1"
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,481][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] http.port: 9600..9700
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,483][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] http.environment: "production"
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,485][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] queue.type: "memory"
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,487][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] queue.drain: false
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,489][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] queue.page_capacity: 67108864
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,491][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] queue.max_bytes: 1073741824
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,496][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] queue.max_events: 0
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,498][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] queue.checkpoint.acks: 1024
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,500][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] queue.checkpoint.writes: 1024
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,501][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] queue.checkpoint.interval: 1000
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,510][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] queue.checkpoint.retry: false
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,512][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] dead_letter_queue.enable: false
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,514][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] dead_letter_queue.max_bytes: 1073741824
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,516][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] dead_letter_queue.flush_interval: 5000
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,520][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] slowlog.threshold.warn: #<Java::OrgLogstashUtil::TimeValue:0x158ff98a>
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,524][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] slowlog.threshold.info: #<Java::OrgLogstashUtil::TimeValue:0x4c14904e>
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,526][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] slowlog.threshold.debug: #<Java::OrgLogstashUtil::TimeValue:0x4f496628>
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,533][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] slowlog.threshold.trace: #<Java::OrgLogstashUtil::TimeValue:0x1d20aae4>
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,541][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] keystore.classname: "org.logstash.secret.store.backend.JavaKeyStore"
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,545][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] keystore.file: "C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/config/logstash.keystore"
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,556][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] path.queue: "C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/data/queue"
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,558][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] path.dead_letter_queue: "C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/data/dead_letter_queue"
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,560][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] path.settings: "C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/config"
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,562][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] path.logs: "C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/logs"
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,576][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] xpack.management.enabled: false
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,579][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] xpack.management.logstash.poll_interval: #<Java::OrgLogstashUtil::TimeValue:0x385865dd>
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,581][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] xpack.management.pipeline.id: ["main"]
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,585][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] xpack.management.elasticsearch.username: "logstash_system"
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,589][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] xpack.management.elasticsearch.hosts: ["https://localhost:9200"]
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,591][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] xpack.management.elasticsearch.ssl.verification_mode: "certificate"
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,593][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] xpack.management.elasticsearch.sniffing: false
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,595][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] xpack.monitoring.enabled: false
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,605][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,607][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] xpack.monitoring.collection.interval: #<Java::OrgLogstashUtil::TimeValue:0x6d9ebd88>
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,610][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] xpack.monitoring.collection.timeout_interval: #<Java::OrgLogstashUtil::TimeValue:0x2e337cff>
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,611][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username: "logstash_system"
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,616][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.ssl.verification_mode: "certificate"
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,618][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.sniffing: false
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,620][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] xpack.monitoring.collection.pipeline.details.enabled: true
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,623][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] xpack.monitoring.collection.config.enabled: true
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,625][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] monitoring.enabled: false
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,634][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] monitoring.elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,638][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] monitoring.collection.interval: #<Java::OrgLogstashUtil::TimeValue:0x14270971>
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,640][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] monitoring.collection.timeout_interval: #<Java::OrgLogstashUtil::TimeValue:0x622314c2>
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,647][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] monitoring.elasticsearch.username: "logstash_system"
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,648][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] monitoring.elasticsearch.ssl.verification_mode: "certificate"
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,653][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] monitoring.elasticsearch.sniffing: false
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,659][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] monitoring.collection.pipeline.details.enabled: true
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,663][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] monitoring.collection.config.enabled: true
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,665][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] node.uuid: ""
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,666][DEBUG][logstash.runner          ] --------------- Logstash Settings -------------------
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,769][DEBUG][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Reading pipeline configurations from YAML {:location=>"C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/config/pipelines.yml"}
[2021-05-21T06:05:36,939][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Setting up metric collection
[2021-05-21T06:05:37,061][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.os] Starting {:polling_interval=>5, :polling_timeout=>120}
[2021-05-21T06:05:37,080][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.cgroup] One or more required cgroup files or directories not found: /proc/self/cgroup, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu
[2021-05-21T06:05:37,353][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] Starting {:polling_interval=>5, :polling_timeout=>120}
[2021-05-21T06:05:37,731][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[2021-05-21T06:05:37,746][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
[2021-05-21T06:05:37,816][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.persistentqueue] Starting {:polling_interval=>5, :polling_timeout=>120}
[2021-05-21T06:05:37,834][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.deadletterqueue] Starting {:polling_interval=>5, :polling_timeout=>120}
[2021-05-21T06:05:37,965][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Starting agent
[2021-05-21T06:05:38,081][DEBUG][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Reading pipeline configurations from YAML {:location=>"C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/config/pipelines.yml"}
[2021-05-21T06:05:38,103][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Starting puma
[2021-05-21T06:05:38,477][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Trying to start WebServer {:port=>9600}
[2021-05-21T06:05:38,681][ERROR][logstash.config.sourceloader] Could not fetch all the sources {:exception=>NoMethodError, :message=>"undefined method `each' for #<String:0x7d3d8211>", :backtrace=>["C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:145:in `merge_pipeline_settings'", "C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/config/source/multi_local.rb:36:in `block in pipeline_configs'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2577:in `map'", "C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/config/source/multi_local.rb:34:in `pipeline_configs'", "C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/config/source_loader.rb:76:in `block in fetch'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2572:in `collect'", "C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/config/source_loader.rb:75:in `fetch'", "C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:188:in `converge_state_and_update'", "C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:126:in `execute'", "C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:409:in `block in execute'", "C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/task.rb:24:in `block in initialize'"]}
[2021-05-21T06:05:38,812][DEBUG][logstash.api.service     ] [api-service] start
[2021-05-21T06:05:38,832][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] An exception happened when converging configuration {:exception=>RuntimeError, :message=>"Could not fetch the configuration, message: undefined method `each' for #<String:0x7d3d8211>", :backtrace=>["C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:195:in `converge_state_and_update'", "C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:126:in `execute'", "C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:409:in `block in execute'", "C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/task.rb:24:in `block in initialize'"]}
[2021-05-21T06:05:38,991][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.os] Stopping
[2021-05-21T06:05:39,122][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] Stopping
[2021-05-21T06:05:39,258][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.persistentqueue] Stopping
[2021-05-21T06:05:39,410][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2021-05-21T06:05:39,419][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.deadletterqueue] Stopping
[2021-05-21T06:05:39,572][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Shutting down all pipelines {:pipelines_count=>0}
[2021-05-21T06:05:39,666][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Converging pipelines state {:actions_count=>0}
[2021-05-21T06:05:39,826][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
[2021-05-21T06:05:39,869][FATAL][org.logstash.Logstash    ] Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
org.jruby.exceptions.SystemExit: (SystemExit) exit
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:747) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:710) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at C_3a_.tools.logstash_minus_7_dot_12_dot_1.lib.bootstrap.environment.<main>(C:\tools\logstash-7.12.1\lib\bootstrap\environment.rb:89) ~[?:?]
```

**One more thing is noticed, bypassing the pipeline.yml file and calling the test.conf directly by specifying the file path, it works successfully.**

> ```
> logstash -f "C:\tools\logstash-7.12.1\config\pipelines\test.conf"
> ```

```
C:\tools\logstash-7.12.1\bin>logstash -f "C:\tools\logstash-7.12.1\config\pipelines\test.conf"
Using JAVA_HOME defined java: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11
WARNING, using JAVA_HOME while Logstash distribution comes with a bundled JDK
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Sending Logstash logs to C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2021-05-21T06:12:04,181][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Log4j configuration path used is: C:\tools\logstash-7.12.1\config\log4j2.properties
[2021-05-21T06:12:04,216][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.12.1", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.13.0 (2.5.7) 2020-08-03 9a89c94bcc Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.11+9-LTS-194 on 11.0.11+9-LTS-194 +indy +jit [mswin32-x86_64]"}
[2021-05-21T06:12:04,478][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2021-05-21T06:12:07,003][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2021-05-21T06:12:08,287][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 93 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 23 keys and 47 values
[2021-05-21T06:12:10,454][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>2, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>250, "pipeline.sources"=>["C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/config/pipelines/test.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x1620a45e run>"}
[2021-05-21T06:12:12,282][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>1.69}
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.jrubystdinchannel.StdinChannelLibrary$Reader (file:/C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/jruby-stdin-channel-0.2.0-java/lib/jruby_stdin_channel/jruby_stdin_channel.jar) to field java.io.FilterInputStream.in
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.jrubystdinchannel.StdinChannelLibrary$Reader
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[2021-05-21T06:12:12,568][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
The stdin plugin is now waiting for input:
[2021-05-21T06:12:12,776][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
tarun...passing an input
{
          "host" => "zteucompass2",
       "message" => "tarun...passing an input\r",
    "@timestamp" => 2021-05-21T06:12:29.779Z,
      "@version" => "1"
}
```

Comment: Is the file called test.yml or test.conf? Can you run Logstash with `logstash --log.level debug` and provide the output you get?

Comment: Sorry, typo mistake, it's test.conf file only and logs with debug mode are attached.

Comment: skipping the pipeline.yml file and directly calling the "test.conf" using command "logstash -f C:\tools\logstash-7.12.1\config\pipelines\test.conf" works, logs are attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my pipelines.yml file, a space after the :? was missing

```
- pipeline.id: test
  path.config: "/C:/tools/logstash-7.12.1/config/pipelines/test.conf"
```

yaml requires a space after the colon, which is the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, pipelines.yml file gets corrupted because of which some unwanted characters get added to it causing this problem and funny part is there is no way you would be able to find the cause as logs won't help much.

Solution :- Delete existing pipelines.yml and create new one and added necessary parameters in it and then test.